# Java Error opening registry key

Tags: java, dll, runtime, registry

I get this error when I try to do anything with Java in command prompt:

```
Error opening registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment.3'
Error: could not find Java.dll
Error: could not find Java 2 Runtime Environment
```

I did screw around with deleting Java directories and registry a few days ago. I restarted computer and java was still working fine, then i restarted it again today and now I get this error. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling but that doesn't seem to work. I have the latest java JRE installed and the path set in the environment variables. Anyone have any clue how to fix this?

Comment: I tried to uninstall java through command prompt and it messed up my uninstaller. So i manually deleted the folder and deleted the registrys pertaining to it. I rebooted and reinstalled Java after that and it worked fine until my next reboot.

Comment: You try to reinstall after the reboot messed it up?  Maybe third time's the charm

Comment: Yes I have, still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried backing up your other files and reformatting your computer?  You could probably do a fresh installation of Java after that.  But this method might be overkill

Comment: Somehow I solved it for my particular issue by downloading runtime even though I already had JDK installed. I leave this here in case that actually works for anyone else.

Answer (score 241, accepted):

Make sure you remove any `java.exe`, `javaw.exe` and `javaws.exe` from your `Windows\System32` folder and if you have an x64 system (Win 7 64 bits) also do the same under `Windows\SysWOW64`.

If you can't find them at these locations, try deleting them from `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath`.

Comment: After removing the "java" executables from my system32 folder, I had to reinstall the JRE.  After that, my problem was solved.  Thanks for the starting point.

Comment: After a security patch installation, I was not able to open eclipse because of this error. Thanks alot! Your solution worked. But I wonder what is the real reason here.

Comment: Worked for me ! Thank you ! Also had to reinstall the JRE.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the effect of these files in system32 folder ?

Comment: run "where java" to see the location of the executable files mentioned above. Mine where on C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath

Answer (score 97):

You will find a folder named "**Oracle**" on ProgramData folder in your windows installed drive. Remove the folder. Hope it will work.
In my case my install drive is C and my path is **C:\ProgramData\Oracle**

Comment: Alternatively, remove `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` from Windows `Path` environment variable

Comment: @GediminasRimsa, i am not sure this path environment variable will present in every case. But thanks for the comment.

Comment: I removed the path from the environmental variables but still had to remove the Oracle folder from the ProgramData folder to get it to work.

Comment: @GediminasRimsa I actually Had to remove the environment Variable after deleting the Oracle Folder in my ProgramData

Answer (score 21):

I had a similar problem. I had installed JDK7 update 1 but couldn't use it (probably because I found a JRE6 that I deleted after installing JDK7). Uninstalling JDK7 was impossible. The solution was to add the JRE registry entries by hand.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment]
"CurrentVersion"="1.7"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\1.7]
"JavaHome"="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre7"
"RuntimeLib"="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre7\\bin\\client\\jvm.dll"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\1.7.0_01]
"JavaHome"="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre7"
"RuntimeLib"="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre7\\bin\\client\\jvm.dll"
```

You'll have to adjust the above to your own directories and version.

If this doesn't help, there's still JavaRa https://singularlabs.com/software/javara/ .

Comment: Regretfully, this didn't work for us on Windows Server 2016. We continue to get "the specified module could not be found"

Comment: Sorry to hear that... try all the other solutions, search for the error message... and if you'll find a solution, please share it here, or create a new question. However... "the specified module could not be found" isn't the error message that was discussed in the original question.

Comment: As of August 2021 http://raproducts.org/wordpress/ just forwards to random clickbait and malware sites.

Comment: @Daz thank you, I have found where the product is now. Can't believe I wrote this almost ten years ago. Don't know if it still works.

Answer (score 12):

Delete these 3 files present in your local at path C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath

```
java.exe
javaw.exe
javaws.exe
```

This solved the issue for me :)

Answer (score 7):

There are 3 locations to check

1. Registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\1.8.0_xxx\JavaHome
2. Java Control Panel- Java tab - View - Path
3. Environment Variables - Path ($env:Path)

All 3 have to align (if you have multiple entires just remove the wrong ones) - thats all

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you remove any java.exe, javaw.exe and javaws.exe  from your system.

- if you have an x32 system (Win XP 32 bits) Windows\System32 folder
- if you have an x64 system (Win 7 64 bits) also do the same under Windows\SysWOW64 folder

Comment: This is just a copy of the accepted answer???

Answer (score 6):

On Windows 10 I had just installed the JDK, and got these errors when checking the version. I had to delete all executable files starting with `java` (i.e. `java.exe`, `javaw.exe` and `javaws.exe`) from `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath`. And then, once deleted, re-run the JDK installer, restart my terminal program and `java -v` works.

Comment: I had to do this but I didn't need to reinstall anything. Deleting the exes fixed the problem

Comment: It's fixed in windows 8 after deleteing those files

Answer (score 2):

I had the same:

```
Error opening registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment
```

Clearing  Windows\SysWOW64  doesn't help for Win7

In my case it installing JDK8 offline helped (from [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html))

Comment: Your solution the only one that worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would have tagged this as a comment but cant (dont have the rep) just wanted to thank Tilman. I was trying to get PDFsam (PDF Split and Merge) to work to no avail.

At launch it would produce an error stating that it could not find JRE 1.6.0. I Have both 32 and 64 bit versions and they check out fine at the java website in their respective browsers.

Tried uninstalling/reinstalling and rebooting repeatedly as well as using JavaRa. No such luck, still no go.

I looked in the registry after reading this post and there was no ...\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\ key so I added each with their respective string values pointing to my x86 version (PDFsam is a 32bit program). This got past the first problem but an error popped up about amd64 libraries suggesting the machine wanted to run the 64bit version. So I changed the paths to the 64bit JRE and PDFsam now works.

FYI - I got here by searching for Java registry keys after I was unable to launch javaw.exe from command prompt (even after adding the requisite paths to system path), making the aforementioned changes solved this as well.

Answer (score 1):

I got this kind of error whe nI had JDK 1.7 before and I installed JAVA JDK 1.8 and pointed my JAVA_HOME and PATH variables to JAVA 1.8 version. When I try to find the java version I got this error. I restarted my machine, and it works . It seems to be we have to restart the machine after modifying the environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

In case a virus scanner (like McAfee) is running, try:

1. Disable virus scanner
2. Uninstall Java (via Control Panel / Programs and Features)
3. Reinstall Java (from [Java.com](http://java.com))
4. Re-enable virus scanner

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Java (via Control Panel / Programs and Features)

Install Java JRE 7 --> OFFLINE <--
Configure JAVA_HOME and Path = `%JAVA_HOME%/bin;%PATH%`

Answer (score 0):

I have Windows 7. I got the same problem after installing: PyCharm.
I wasn't satisfied with PyCharm, so I decided to use Eclipse instead. This is when I discovered that things went wrong with my JDK. I used to have Java.9.x. So I decided to uninstall it and get the newer version (at my time it was Java.11.x. The same problem persisted. 
I followed most of the steps mentioned above in the post like:
- Removing all java*.exe files, 
- removing Java related entries from the registry. 
- Cleaning-up all unnecessary Java folders. However nothing helped. I still had something in the system referring to a broken Java pathname.

What really brought remedy is the following:
 - Uninstalled what ever version of JDK I had at the moment.
 - Re-Installed the last JDK version I had before the problem took place
 - Properly uninstall that version. 
 - Install whatever latest version of SDK. ..

That's it .. at this point everything returned to normal ... Except that Java.11.xx did not fix the system path automatically, I had to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

I followed multiple answers from above and got my issue resolved.

Issue:

Javac  was on 13 from jdk but java was using 1.8 from jre  so java threw incompatible runtime error

Fix:

1. Under Control Panel -> Programs: I uninstalled 1.8 (named Java 8 runtime) and DID NOT touch the other one (named Java (TM) SE Development Kit 13)
2. Deleted java.exe, javac.exe and javawc.exe files from:
   a. C:\Windows\system32
   b. C:\Windows\SysWOW64
   c. C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath
3. The environment variable JDK_HOME was pointing to 13 but JAVA_HOME was pointing to 1.8 so i pointed JAVA_HOME to also use 13 which was C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1
4. There was a Path variable under both User variables and system variables sections.
   For the one in user variables section, i added the string %JDK_HOME% - which translated automatically to the physical path.
   For the one under system variables, I deleted the path C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath and added C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1\bin

All good now! Thanks to all the people who answered, you rock!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to delete java references from system32, SysWOW64, and delete javapath from ProgramData\Oracle\Java. It solves the issue

Answer (score 0):

If you have "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath" in your PATH, just make sure that the java bin path entries are present before this entry in your PATH.

I was facing the exact same issue, and I just moved the java jdk/jre bin path entries up in the list, above the oracle entry and it resolved my issue.