# Error: Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'\CurrentVersion'?

Tags: java, exception, environment, runtimeexception

When I run:
C:\Users\ashahria\Downloads>java -jar schemaSpy_5.0.0.jar

I get the error below. What is wrong? How can I fix it?

> Error: Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'\CurrentVersion'
>
> has value '1.5', but '1.7' is required.
> Error: could not find java.dll
> Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.

Comment: You can read this posts: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t145273-java-jdk-and-java-jre-system-properties.html & http://aosgrp.com/products/jack/documentation_and_instructi/jack_programming_faq/my_windows_computer_tells_m.html & http://www.coderanch.com/t/323565/java/java/Not-able-run-java-exe

Answer (score 115, accepted):

On my Windows 7 machine, it was solved by doing the following:

1. In the *START* menu type "***regedit***" to open the Registry (be careful doing this)
2. Go to "**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE**" on the left-hand side registry explorer/tree menu
3. Click "**SOFTWARE**" within the "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" registries
4. Click "**JavaSoft**" within the "SOFTWARE" registries
5. Click "**Java Runtime Environment**" within the "JavaSoft" list of registries
6. Highlight "**CurrentVersion**" (should see it in the main registry key explorer window on the right)
7. Change version to "**1.7**"

That is all... should work. Short of that, if you've already tried some other guides and/or messed up your registries, the most certain way to deal with the problem is to delete all previous versions of Java (using "Programs and Features" uninstall process) and then re-install just the version you want to work with. I'd suggest the distribution site at:
http://java.com (as it usually has the most stable version)

Or look for a specific version you need from Oracle's site:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/

Comment: I had 1.7 and 1.8 installed, but no %JAVA_PATH% variable and Java was not in %PATH%. For some reason, executing `java -version` from `C:\Windows\System32\` gave me the same error as in the question, but executing it from any other directory worked fine and reported the latest version. I did this and everything worked, so I assume some update failed to update all files, because in my case I had to downgrade from 1.8 to 1.7.

Comment: With [`procmon.exe`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx) I figured out that my registry path was `HKLM/SOFTWARE/Wow6432Node/JavaSoft/Java Runtime Environment/CurrentVersion`. This might be due to it being a x64 build of java (I was downgrading 1.8 to 1.7 to work with FlashDevelop).

Comment: To add to this, in my case I couldn't simply change the version because for some reason I didn't have that version under Java Runtime Environment. What fixed it for me was adding a new key under Java Runtime Environment called '1.7' and in there I added a new String value for JavaHome and set that to the JRE home.

Comment: Also, is good to remember that if it's greater than 2Gb, it's necessary to install the 64-bit Java

Comment: What makes it to happen this error?

Comment: Mostly installing Java in non-standard ways (such as unzipping & registering .vs. running platform-specific installer) or when a specific version an application expects is missing, often an older version.

Answer (score 57):

I had various JDK from 1.5 to 1.7 installed on my PC. I had a need to learn JDK1.8 so installed and my earlier versions of Eclipse (depended on earlier versions of JDK) and I got errors launching my Eclipse IDE, on the command line I tried to check the Java Version and got the error below,

```
C:\>java -version
Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\CurrentVersion'
has value '1.8', but '1.6' is required.
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.
```

Solution:-
I removed

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
```

from the PATH variable and moved %JAVA%\bin to the start of the PATH variable, that solved the problem for me.

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: I also removed javapath from the beginning and it didn't help. So I put the JAVA_HOME at the beginning not the end and it worked

Comment: You are awesome :)

Comment: Works. Perfect.

Comment: Remember to find the same for User and System variables and remove them. Then add Java installation path to the path variable.

Answer (score 36):

Go to 'c:/Windows/System32' and delete the java.exe, javaw.exe and javaws.exe there.
See at [Registry Key '...' has value '1.7', but '1.6' is required. Java 1.7 is Installed and the Registry is Pointing to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277496/registry-key-has-value-1-7-but-1-6-is-required-java-1-7-is-installed)

Comment: Also check if they are in `C:/Windows/SysWOW64` instead.

Comment: if u cant find it at suggested locations, try deleting it from here: **C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath** ,it worked for me

Answer (score 11):

`set PATH=c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin;%PATH%`

this will work if you are working on command prompt

Comment: This can be done. even without admin rights.

Answer (score 5):

you may follow these steps :

- set JAVA_HOME to jdk[without bin folder]
- set PATH as %JAVA_HOME%/bin;
- put java.exe , javaw.exe & javaws.exe to C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath [I was having problem here].
- double click on the java.exe
- Also check and edit the registry value for JAVA current version if required.

it worked for me :)

Answer (score 3):

Your java version is 1.5 (you have jdk 1.5). The jar requires java version 1.7 (you should have jdk 1.7). You should download and install the 1.7 jdk from this website:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-se-jdk-7-download-432154.html

Comment: I have already install 1.5 and 1.6 and 1.7 all with their jre en jdk

Comment: Then you need to know which version your OS is using. To do that go to Command Prompt and type **java**, if the version is less than 1.7 or 7 then you should fix your **JAVA_HOME** envrionmental path variable

Answer (score 3):

I had Java 1.8 but had to downgrade to Java 1.6 for some reason. When I uninstalled java 1.8 and ran the command "Java -Version" from the command prompt, I got the error -

Error: Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'\CurrentVersion'

has value '1.6', but '1.8' is required.
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.

Uninstalling 1.6 and then reinstalling 1.6 fixed the issue for me :-)

Answer (score 2):

Adjust the sequence of your environment variable %path% to make sure jre 1.7 is the default one.

Answer (score 2):

One Good solution is to restart the PC, this will make the right entry in the Registry of the PC. Restarting solves my problem

Answer (score 2):

Just Reinstall JDK 1.7 it will work.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the steps mentioned by @bcmoney but for me the current version was already set to the latest version. In my it was Java8.

I had various versions of java installed (java6, java7 and java8). I got the same error but instead of 1.5 and 1.7 i got 1.7 and 1.8. I uninstalled java6 on my windows 8.1 machine. After which i tried java -version in command prompt and the error did not appear.

I am not sure whether this is the right answer but it worked for me so i thought it would help the community too.

Comment: Did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7425644/918608

Answer (score 2):

I just uninstalled my Java8 update and tried again. It worked ok!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue after updating the Java JDK, but had not yet restarted my command prompt.  After restarting the command prompt, everything worked fine. Presumably, because the PATH variable need to be reset after the JDK update.

Answer (score 1):

Other times you might have installed Java 7 and 8 both or twice, and from Add/remove programs unistall one of them and it should work.