# Sencha Cmd 5 + Java 8 Error

Tags: java, windows, sencha-cmd

After installing Java 8 JDK on my Windows build server, I'm running into the following error when executing the `sencha` command:

```
C:\> sencha

Error: Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'\CurrentVersion'
has value '1.8', but '1.7' is required.
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.
```

The Sencha Cmd Guide implies that Java 8 isn't supported yet (however Sencha Cmd works fine on my Mac OS X workstation with Java 8):

> Sencha Cmd requires Java Runtime Environment version 1.7 to support
>   all functionality...

I've still got JDK 7 installed on the server. Is there any way to force Sencha Cmd to use a different JDK install? Changing JAVA_HOME and PATH sysenvs does not work, and editing the registry isn't an option.

**UPDATE:** I've run across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277496/registry-key-has-value-1-7-but-1-6-is-required-java-1-7-is-installed) where multiple `java.exe` files cause the same error (and that's definitely a possibility here) however maven, ant, tomcat, jenkins, and a slew of other Java tools are working fine. I've only seen this error with Sencha Cmd.

Answer (score 9):

To make this slightly more concrete, I followed ben's advice and created the following **sencha.bat** file in my installation directory:

```
@echo off
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
set SENCHA_HOME=%~dp0
java -jar "%SENCHA_HOME%\sencha.jar" %*
```

and I renamed the existing **sencha.exe** to something innocuous.  Now I can simply type "sencha" at the command line without extra fuss.  Of course, if you have a different minor version of Java 7, you'll need to edit the JAVA_HOME above.

Comment: Great! With this solution, there is no need to manipulate the registry or path environment variables or downgrade android tools or something else.

Comment: This is a good solution, it seems like the sencha.exe is not respecting or is otherwise resetting the PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 7):

My 'Path' environment variable are mapping 'C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath' which contains 3 shortcuts for following files from 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_xx\bin':

- java.exe
- javaw.exe
- javaws.exe

But these files are also present in 'C:\Windows\System32'; if you call 'java' from this directory you will have the same error (Error: Registry key...)
By replacing these 3 files in 'C:\Windows\System32' by the one's from 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_xx\bin'; it will solve the issue.

Comment: This was the issue for me, thanks! You can test to see if this is your issue by simply renaming these files with a .old extension in the System32 directory and then re-running. If this was the problem, the errors will simply go away :)

Answer (score 3):

Try the following workaround to use the latest SenchaCMD working with JDK8:

1. check your PATH environment variable; especially the correct java installation path(s)
2. open the command prompt and go to the sencha-cmd folder
3. to use SenchaCMD just execute the "sencha.jar"-file with java:

   ```
   java -jar sencha.jar
   ```

Now, you should see all version informations about the executed SenchaCMD-Tool.

Tested with JDK 1.8.0u25 and SenchaCMD 5.1.0.26 on W7 Prof. x64

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same thing,  found that I was required to update the sencha cmd itself.  I had extjs 5.1 cmd 5.1.0 , downloaded extjs 6.0.1 and tried to sencha app upgrade {new_extjs6_path} my app.  Received the above error,  figured out I was required to update cmd to 6.0.1 as well.