# I can't run java files on my Notepad++

Tags: java, runtime, notepad++

I have my notepad++ setup to compile/run Java files via NppEXEC, compiling is fine but I get the following error when I try to run

```
Error: Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'\CurrentVersion'
has value '1.8', but '1.7' is required.
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.
```

I already made a thread on this earlier, but it got closed noting that I should try the solutions in the thread provided below, but they did not help me as I've stated in the previous thread so I was wondering if anyone could help me in my current situation?

I have already tried the solutions provided in this [Registry Key '...' has value '1.7', but '1.6' is required. Java 1.7 is Installed and the Registry is Pointing to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277496/registry-key-has-value-1-7-but-1-6-is-required-java-1-7-is-installed) thread, I deleted the java files out of system 32 folder and removed the oracle path, but I am still getting this error. My registry shows that it is 1.7 http://gyazo.com/814f5167af354f5f3d0d0666e31cf58a as well and still the same.

I have the following atm User Variables

---

```
PATH = C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin;C:\Windows\System32;
```

---

System Variables

---

```
CLASSPATH = C:\ConsoleDir 

JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20 

PATH = C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin;C:\Windows\System32; 

QTJAVA = C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip (I don't know if this is relevant
```

Comment: What about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644992/error-registry-key-software-javasoft-java-runtime-environment-currentversion

Comment: Do you have multiple java versions installed?

Comment: Ascalonian I've tried the registry one but I wasn't having luck with it, it is on 1.7 currently.

@OldProgrammer, I have this at the moment, http://gyazo.com/7e3d4cfd6fb60e9ab7d835a3c6fc3907 , not sure what to remove from that to benefit my current status.