# Why am I still getting a cannot find Java SE Runtime Environment?

Tags: java, runtime, environment

These are the errors I get when I try to run a simple java version in the command window.[image]

I followed the advice on [Error: Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'\CurrentVersion'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644992/error-registry-key-software-javasoft-java-runtime-environment-currentversion).
When I went on regedit, here's what I saw 
[image]

Which meant that there was nothing to change - right runtime version. I then did the next step which was to "delete all previous versions of Java (using "Programs and Features" uninstall process) and then re-install just the version you want to work with"
However, that didn't work either......
Here is my current java directory(see that i have everything installed)
[image]

And my current environmental variables are

```
JAVA_HOME - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71

Path - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin
```

which i believe are correct as well from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/install-windows-189425.html

Does anyone know how i can get rid of this issue? I could do one more uninstall/install but I think that be a waste of time and won't make a difference.

Comment: isn't it `java -version` ?

Comment: didnt matter tried that too, same error. Fixed that syntax by the way as well

Comment: Does java.dll exists in path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\jre\bin?

Comment: there is no bin, just a lib, do i have to uninstall/install the jdk as well?

Comment: I don't think is off topic, there have been questions like this posted in the past

Comment: Should i just delete the jdk? There is no uninstall for that.

Comment: Have you already tried re-installing it?

Comment: echo %JAVA_HOME% command will show your jdk path??

Comment: @merlin2011 just JRE, there was no uninstall for jdk

Comment: @YeWin thanks for that command, I have the right jdk path. I think i just need to delete it and reinstall it

Comment: Is the issue that I deleted java.dll? I don't remember messing around in that directory or deleting that library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I want to thank @almas-shaikh for this answer. His comment made me check over C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\jre\bin and see that there was no java.dll library file inside that directory. What I did next was just deleting the jdk and reinstalling it via jdk-7u71-windows-x64.exe executable. 
Now when I execute java -home, I get [image]

Now the part I don't get is how the java.dll library file was deleted in the first place......

Comment: I do have my java.dll in place but I'm still getting the error. Any idea why?

Comment: Confusing documentation and installation process by Oracle. For anyone else without missing DLLs, turns out the jdk installer doesn't automatically setup the JAVA_HOME environment variable so once you set that appropriately, `java -version` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the steps.
I hope, it will help you.

**Step 1:** 
Delete all previous versions of Java (using "Programs and Features" uninstall process).
If java folder is remain in "C:/Program Files/...", please delete it.

**Step 2:**
Clean up your registry(delete your java key). Please follow the below link for step by step clean up
https://java.com/en/download/help/manual_regedit.xml

**Step 3:**
Reinstall Java and sets system variable JAVA_HOME to your JDK path.
Eg: 
JAVA_HOME - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71
Path - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin

**Step 4**
If step 3 is success, check with below command 
1) echo %JAVA_HOME%
2) java -version

Comment: I figured it out. See my answer. Thanks for your help though :)

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. Turns out, even when you have 64-bit OS, your browser is most likely 32-bit and therefore your JAVA too. You need to manually install 64-bit JAVA.

I hope that will help.

Answer (score 1):

java installation will create a folder similar to this C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java. rename and again try cmd java -version.

make sure you have path variable set to latest jre/bin folder

Answer (score 0):

try adding "%JAVA_HOME%\bin;" in the Path section instead of this "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin", should make no difference but just try it like this.

Comment: Yeah thanks but i think it was the fact that I was missing the java.dll library file. I don't know what happened to it

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this answer, but this is how I ran into the problem and then solved it.

I had `Java 14.0.2` installed and I needed `IntelliJ` and `Maven` installed. This computer is an enterprise computer so I didn't have much saying on the installation process. I suppose `IntelliJ` came with `Java 10.0.1` or that IT installed it as part of their process and it of course threw all my system out of the window.

So to fix this, I had to get someone from IT to unlock the admin things for me, and then:

- I deleted the JRE paths with `10.0.1`
- Under the Windows tool to uninstall software, I deleted `Java 10.0.1` JRE and JDK.
- Under the Java directory, also moved or deleted those folders
- And then I tested `IntelliJ` and the Terminal with `java -version` and `javac -version` to check if I was getting the same results (got `14.0.2`, nice, that is what I was expecting)
- And then checked `Maven` with `mvn -version` for the `apache` feedback as well, which will also return which JDK it's running.

No need to fiddle with registry, or even restart the computer (just to restart the Terminal after Path changes).