# Error: Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'\CurrentVersion'

Tags: java, version

I get

'Error: Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'\CurrentVersion'

```
has value '1.8', but '1.7' is required.
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.'
```

error after I just type java on command prompt.

I see it is answered in the following link : 
1. [Java Error opening registry key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362037/java-error-opening-registry-key)
2. [Error: Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'\CurrentVersion'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644992/error-registry-key-software-javasoft-java-runtime-environment-currentversion)

But
I do not have access to C:/windows/system32 or 64...I am not an admin and contacting admin is not an option.

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I did the following as posted by someone in the above links posted in my question.

1. In the START menu type "regedit" to open the Registry (be careful doing this)
2. Go to "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" on the left-hand side registry explorer/tree menu
3. Click "SOFTWARE" within the "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" registries
4. Click "JavaSoft" within the "SOFTWARE" registries
5. Click "Java Runtime Environment" within the "JavaSoft" list of registries
6. Highlight "CurrentVersion" (should see it in the main registry key explorer window on the right)
7. Change version to "1.7"