# Can not create java virtual machine popup message in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jvm

I want to log the GC details and added following VM argument in eclipse:

```
-verbose:gc 
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
-Xmx768M
```

Now when I launch the application I get an error dialog that states "can not create java virtual machine".

What is the problem?

Comment: have you checked that these are valid switches for the specific jvm version that Eclipse is trying to launch?

Answer (score 2):

The following [link](http://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/eclipseCommLineArgs.html) explains how to supply VM arguments in eclipse.

> Now when I launch the application I get an error dialog that states
>   "can not create java virtual machine".

There could be quite a few reasons for this. One common one is that eclipse cant find the java executable. You can open the eclipse.ini file and add:

```
-vm
 /opt/jdk/bin/javaw.exe
```

You should replace the above path with the path of your executable.

Answer (score 0):

We were facing a similar problem. We uninstalled java 7 and replaced it with java 6 (http://www.java.com/en/download/manual_v6.jsp) and this worked for us. (above suggested changes - editing .ini file with vm, etc. - didn't work for us! it just brought up a different error message).

One issue we did face is in getting 'java -version' in command prompt to work. We were seeing the following error: "java error in opening registry key". The selected answer (removing java.exe, etc. files from windows/system32 folder) at the following link worked and we were good to go.

[Java Error opening registry key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362037/java-error-opening-registry-key)

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have multiple entries for "-vm" in your eclipse.ini file. Multiple entries will cause this error to appear.

Answer (score 0):

I have found very easy solution for this just delete eclipse.ini file but backup first.

i had this same problem many times and finally i deleted this and i have no more problem.

it also increased loading time. now my eclipse starts faster then earlier.