# Launching jarsigner.exe on windows os which jdk/jre not installed by installer

Tags: java, jarsigner

I've embedded jre files to my applications setup, i can use java.exe to perform some java specific tasks.

And i want to use jarsigner.exe but when i launch jarsigner, it checks some registry keys, and could not found (because jre is not insatalled by jre setup) them and gives error.

How can i specify java.exe path to jarsigner

so that it should use java.exe that i point instead of checking registry.

error log:

> Error opening registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment
>
> Error: could not find java.dll
>
> Error: could not find Java SE Runtime Environment

I wonder are there any extra parameters for jarsigner may be that defines JAVA_HOME dir, or anything else that defines where java.exe is exists.

Comment: "I've embedded jre files to my applications setup". Clearly you need to embed some *JDK* files into your application setup, and clearly you should use the JDK's own installer to do so.

Comment: @EJP: yes, i actually added some jdk files (jli.dll, msvcr71.dll, and tools.jar with jarsiger.exe) to application setup, these work fine on a system that  jre installed but jdk not installed.

Answer (score 2):

There are no specific command-line parameters, however while invoking `jarsigner`, you can still set the `java.home` property to point to your desired JRE bundled with your application.

For instance, you could invoke the `jarsigner` with either:

- [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) and set the `java.home` property,
- or a variant of [`Runtime.exec()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) allowing to set the `envp` environment variables,
- or a batch/shell script and set the `JAVA_HOME` property in it.

Comment: thanks for answer. i use c++ to invoke jarsigner.exe. i tried to do with batch file, bu got same error.

Comment: batch file content :set JAVA_HOME="C:\jre6\"
jarsigner.exe
pause

Answer (score 1):

To make jarsigner work with JRE instead of JDK. Need to bundle these files in JRE from JDK

From \bin\jarsigner.exe to \bin\jarsigner.exe
From \bin\msvcr100.dll to \bin\msvcr100.dll
From \bin\jli.dll to \bin\jli.dll
From \lib\tool.jar to \lib\tool.jar
I tested with this and found it working for me.

Comment: I just needed \bin\jarsigner.exe and \lib\tool.jar.  Make sure these are from the same version of the SDK as the installed JRE, or you'll get a version error.

Answer (score 0):

Stolen from [Java Error opening registry key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362037/java-error-opening-registry-key)

Remove if any.

on 32 bit machine

java.exe, javaw.exe and javaws.exe from your Windows\System32 folder

on 64 bit machine

remove from Windows\SysWOW64.

Comment: i could not do that jre/jdk would be installed or not. i want from my jarsigner.exe to use jre i provide.