# exit code 2 error in eclipse installation

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I wish to learn application development and have been trying to start up **eclipse**. I have installed `jdk1.7.0_71`, since jdk8 is not compatible. I have a windows-64 bit device and have installed 64 bit versions of both **eclipse luna** and **jdk7**. Initially it showed me exit `code 13` error but after re installing all software it displays exit `code 2`. i also think the .dll file is missing from the downloaded package, even though I downloaded and extracted all files accurately. Please help.
I have set the path for java as Path : **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin**. Is this accurate?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and was trying to install different versions of `JDK: 1.6, 1.7, 1.8.`

It didn't help much.

The problem was resolved when I changed `PATH` variable by removing

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
```

In *command prompt* I also ran following commands:

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25
set PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin;%PATH%
```

But I think the most important was to remove
 `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;` from the PATH.

*I think it might help u*

Answer (score 0):

You installed the latest JDK and so you need to point your eclipse configuration file to point to the latest JDK.

**1)** *Open your eclipse.ini file which is in your installed eclipse folder.*

**2)** *Modify/Add the Java version to be your installed JDK version.*

**For example -**

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20130521-0416
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

The other thing is to look at the Java path of your environment variable which you set to be wrong one - [Eclipse: JVM terminated. Exit code=2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25614637/eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-2)