# Eclipse startup error JVC terminated exit code 2

Tags: eclipse, startup

I'm getting this problem when I start-up. I managed to get it working perfectly then I did a system restore (which brought me back to before I had it) and since then its not worked, though I re-installed it and did everything as I had before. According to the uninstall/change program menu I have Java 7 Update 75 (64-bit) and Java SE Development Kit 7 Update 75 (64-bit) installed.!

Thanks a lot guys!

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=2
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-jar
C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
-os win32
-ws win32
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.4.2.v20150204-1700\splash.bmp
-launcher C:\Users\tom\Desktop\eclipse\eclipse.exe
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library
C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20150204-1316\eclipse_1608.dll
-startup
C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdate 1f18_68
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-vm C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xmsm40
-Xmx512m
-jar
C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
```

Comment: C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe looks suspect.

Comment: Coud you please elaborate on that? Any idea what I could do to fix it?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/25616276/27905

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried it but I had no java path in the system variables so I couldn't delete it. I tried deleting the path in my user variables (above the system ones) but it didn't fix it.

For some reason I have multiple jdk versions, should I delete some? I have jdk1.7.0_75 and jdk1.8.0_40 under my Java file in program files (I also have multiple jre versions in my Program files X86; jre1.8.0_31 and jre1.8.0_40 whilst still having one in my non X86 program files folder).

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue as long as only one of them, the one you want to use, is listed as part of the PATH variable.

Answer (score 0):

Answer can be found here - [Eclipse: JVM terminated. Exit code=2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25614637/eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-2)

"The problem was resolved when I changed PATH variable by removing

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
```

In command prompt I also ran following commands:

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25
set PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin;%PATH%
```

But I think the most important was to remove C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath; from the PATH."