# Eclipse Popping in Unexpected error

Tags: eclipse, ide

i have jdk-8u65-windows-i586 installed on window 8. I have properly done with environment variables. I am trying to start coding using Eclipse but its showing me the following error. >[Error SnapShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvrzF.jpg)

What Should i do? Thanks

Comment: What is the output of `java -version` executed on the command line?

Comment: Specifically, it looks like answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26499511/1500563 may help you.

Comment: Actually, http://stackoverflow.com/a/31729109/639520 is the best possible answer. Removing `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` from the system `PATH` is good advice in general, though.