# I get the following error message when I try and open eclipse for C/C++

Tags: c, eclipse

I have a working Eclipse java version (java mars) but recently tried to download the C/C++ version. I also downloaded MinGW and it sits in the same directory as the eclipse c folder. The problem is that when I launch eclipse, rather than opening up, I get the following error message:
[image]

I recently redownloaded jdk and jre if that might have caused this.

What does this mean and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Try the answers from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25614637/eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-2

Comment: strongly suggest: do not place two different multi-file applications in the same directory.   Suggest empty the directory, re-install eclipse,  In a different//new directory install MinGW.