# Eclipse Neon.3 fails to launch after install

Tags: eclipse

I've installed Eclipse Neon.3 on my windows 7 machine, after the install process has finished, the installer has an option to 'launch now', which I do and the IDE boots up and works as expected.

However when I close eclipse and then reopen it, I get a crash which prevents it from booting up (sorry for this being a picture, but there doesn't seem to be an easy way to copy the text):
[image]

The version I've installed is Release 4.6.3, and the build ID is 20170314.  I've installed and removed it 3 times and observed the same behaviour each time.  I've tried doing a reset between boots and installs.  I've also tried inspecting my environment variables, which look like this:

JAVA_HOME:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91
PATH: %PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin

Is this a known issue, or do I have something wrong in my setup?  Prior to this I discovered 4 versions of the jre/jdk on my machine, and two versions of eclipse.  I think I have correctly removed all but the one referenced from my java home, and I entirely removed eclipse and downloaded the latest version (neon.3).

Comment: Did you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25614637/eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-2?

Comment: I have, thanks for the heads up but this wasn't the problem, kind of.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the issue, and whilst I'm still not entirely sure why it was a problem, here is how I fixed it.

I opened a terminal and ran 'java -version' (I should have done this first).  It was failing to find java.exe, despite the bin folder being on the path.  Running this revealed that it was actually calling a shortcut to java.exe found in 'c /programdata/oracle/java/javapath/' which pointed to a now non existent version of java.

So long story short, if you have a similar problem, check if you have shortcuts in the folder 'c /programdata/oracle/java/javapath/java.exe' and ensure they point to the correct program.