# Java PATH issue (works from java installation directory but not anywhere else)

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmd, environment-variables

I am getting this error when I run Java from C:

```
C:\>java -version
Error: opening registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.
```

However, it works fine if I call it from installation directory.

```
C:\Java\bin>java -version
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I have the installation directory path in my %PATH% environment variable.

```
C:\>echo %PATH%
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\java\bin
C:\>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Java
```

What else I am missing in here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks similar to this [Java Error opening registry key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362037/java-error-opening-registry-key)

as a final step try reinstalling java