# How to set java home in windows 7 for JDK 11?

Tags: java, java-home

Unable to set java_home in windows 7. i have update the path to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11 in system advanced environment variables still from command prompt am getting the following errors.

Error: opening registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.

Comment: did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362037/java-error-opening-registry-key

Comment: i have tried not working.

Comment: Thanks all after restart system its working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to surround the value by quotes in order to escape the space in it: `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11"`.

Comment: No its not working. Its not required i was earlier using java 8 i never provided quotes. Thanks for Reply.