# Not able to get java version in windows

Tags: java, incompatibility, unsupported-class-version

When I run on console `javac -version`, I get the version number as `11.0.2`, but when I run `java -version` I get the following error:

```
Error: opening registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.
```

What should I do about this?

Which version of `JRE` do I need to install for `JDK 11.0.2`,so that I won't get any compatibility issues which executing java code?

Comment: How did you install which version of Java?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362037/java-error-opening-registry-key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Check path.**
To make sure that Windows can find the Java compiler and interpreter:

> Select Start -> Computer -> System Properties -> Advanced system
>   settings -> Environment Variables -> System variables -> PATH.

Prepend `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.x.x\bin` to the beginning of the `PATH` variable.

Comment: Thanks, It helped...!