# Eclipse: "Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment"

Tags: java, windows, eclipse

I have just downloaded Eclipse and tried to run it, and it gave me this error message:

> Error: opening registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment
>
> Error: could not find java.dll
>
> Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.

After closing the errors, it sends me to this site:
https://download.eclipse.org/oomph/jre/?vm=1_1_8_0_64_0&pn=Eclipse%20Installer&pu=http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Installer&pi=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/jre/128x128.png

I have already reinstalled the jdk multiple times.
After following some other posts i saw, i have also made sure that %JAVA_HOME% was included in PATH
(%JAVA_HOME% = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1)

to `java -version` i got:

> java version "1.8.0_231"
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_231-b11)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.231-b11, mixed mode)

Thank you in advance for the help!

**Edit:**
I had both jdk-13.0.1 and jre 1.8.0 installed
After reinstalling only jdk 13.0.1 (and uninstalling jre 1.8.0), java -version gave me:

> java version "13.0.1" 2019-10-15
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 13.0.1+9)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 13.0.1+9, mixed mode, sharing)

I'm using Windows 10 Pro
EclipseIDE 2019-12 64bit

Comment: One thing I noticed is the JAVA_HOME path refers to JDK 13, while the "java -version" command points to 1.8. Specify the version of Windows and Eclipse you have used in this question. Also, make sure you restart the PC after installing Java.

Comment: @ShankarPS Edited the question to adress your concerns

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362037/java-error-opening-registry-key) answer maybe you messed up with your registry, make sure all java removed first and reinstall JRE.
For me if I want to develop java apps, I would install JDK instead of JRE, after install pls check `java` & `javac` command exist

Comment: Just did it. Didn't have to delete anything after uninstallation. After reinstalling jdk, the java and javac commands worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

> 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment
>
> Error: could not find java.dll
>
> Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment. After closing the
>   errors, it sends me to this site:
>   https://download.eclipse.org/oomph/jre/?vm=1_1_8_0_64_0&pn=Eclipse%20Installer&pu=http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Installer&pi=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/jre/128x128.png

I have already reinstalled the JDK multiple times. After following some other posts I saw, I have also made sure that `%JAVA_HOME%` was included in PATH `(%JAVA_HOME% = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1)`

to java -version I got:

```
java version "1.8.0_231"
```

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_231-b11)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.231-b11, mixed mode)
Thank you in advance for the help!

Edit:
I had both `jdk-13.0.1` and `jre 1.8.0` installed
After reinstalling only `jdk 13.0.1` (and uninstalling `jre 1.8.0`), java -version gave me:

```
java version "13.0.1" 2019-10-15
```

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 13.0.1+9)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 13.0.1+9, mixed mode, sharing)
I'm using Windows 10 Pro
EclipseIDE 2019-12 64bit
share edit
asked
1 hour ago

Csalagovits Máté
1●11 bronze badge edited
5 secs ago

One thing I noticed is the JAVA_HOME path refers to JDK 13, while the "java -version" command points to 1.8. Specify the version of Windows and Eclipse you have used in this question. Also, make sure you restart the PC after installing Java. – Shankar P S 52 mins ago
@ShankarPS Edited the question to adress your concerns – Csalagovits Máté 2 mins ago