# RuntimeError: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number after setting JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to start pyspark using VSCode but i am getting the follow errors:

```
Java not found and JAVA_HOME environment variable is not set.
Install Java and set JAVA_HOME to point to the Java installation directory.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Erevos\Desktop\Pyspark\LearnSpark.py", line 5, in <module>
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("MyApp").getOrCreate()
  File "C:\Users\Erevos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 477, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
  File "C:\Users\Erevos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 512, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
  File "C:\Users\Erevos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 198, in __init__
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
  File "C:\Users\Erevos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 432, in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
  File "C:\Users\Erevos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyspark\java_gateway.py", line 106, in launch_gateway
    raise RuntimeError("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")
RuntimeError: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

i have already set the JAVA_HOME = path, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1RW6.png)

Moreover, i have downloaded the folders required: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtVPc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to output the env variable

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

and check if it's correct.

If not correct check again your JAVA_HOME assignment.

Then, close and reopen the command prompt again that runs the java process (or the OS user session) and type `java -version` to check if it installed successfully.

If the java command fails follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362037/java-error-opening-registry-key).

Follow this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/index.html) to have more info about JAVA_HOME.

Comment: What i am getting when running echo %JAVA_HOME% is: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20. when running java -version i am getting: Error: opening registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.

Comment: Amd java -version output?

Comment: just updated the previous comment.

Comment: It seems you have issues with the java installation. Try to follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362037/java-error-opening-registry-key

Comment: Thank you, i will now follow the instructions provided by the link you sent me.

Comment: Marked as accepted as the problem bypassed and this is a new one. Kind regards.